# LINQ for records in another table via JOIN table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

If I have TableXXX (ID, Name) and TableYYY(ID, Name) and Join table XXXYYY (XXXID, YYYID), how do I write a LINQ expression so that:

```
SELECT * FROM TableYYY
  WHERE ID IN (SELECT YYYID FROM XXXYYY
                 WHERE XXXID IN  (SELECT ID FROM TableXXX WHERE [some condition])
```

This could also be something like:

```
SELECT y.* FROM TableYYY y
  JOIN XXXYYY j
    ON j.YYYID = y.ID
  JOIN XXX x
    ON j.XXXID = x.ID
  WHERE [condition]
```

But the problem is, using Telerik OpenAccess ORM, join table XXXYYY does not exist as its own table, but is a List as part of TableXXX and TableYYY

I am sure it is something simple, like
return context.TableYYY.Where(x=>x.Contains(?));

Comment: It looks like I figured it out....

Comment: tableXXX.SelectMany(y => y.tableYYY);